# Autolayout constraint for iPhone 8 and 8+ using storyboard

Tags: xcode, autolayout, storyboard

How to define separate constraints for iPhone 8 and 8+?

Since both have different width. Is it possible to differentiate it via storyboard.

Basically I want to set different x and y margins for both phones.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't separate layout for iPhone 8 and 8+ in storyboard.because Autolayout is based on size class and there is no size class available that separate iphone 8 and 8+.

for more info : https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/size-classes-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-8-74f20a541195.

Answer (score 0):

Custom constraint class
IBDesignable & IBInspectable

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

  @IBInspectable
  var iPhone8: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
      if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 667 &&
         UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX == 375 {
        constant = iPhone8
      }
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable
  var iPhone8Plus: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
      if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX == 414 &&
         UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 736 {
        constant = iPhone8Plus
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Set constraint custom class

[image]

[image]

[image]